# Analyse of a simple trigonometric sequence

Tags: real-analysis

I can't figure out how i prove that the sequence $$ W_{n} = \cos ({\ln({n}) )} $$ converge or diverge. I can say that the sequence is limited because $\mid W_{n}\mid  = \mid \cos ({\ln({n}) )}\mid  \hspace{0.1cm}  \leq 1 $, but at the same time the sequence is periodic and i don't know an idea to show that the sequence is monotonic, in the case that it converges, or why it diverges.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How can you say that it is periodic....

Comment: well, in fact the sequence is not periodic, what is periodic is the  cosine function, i made a mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limit does not exist. By assuming
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\cos(\log n)=L $$
and replacing $n$ with $n^2$ we get that $L$ is a root of
$$ 2z^2-1 = z, $$
but replacing $n$ with $n^3$ we get that $L$ is a root of
$$ 4z^3-3z = z, $$
hence the only possibility is $L=1$. However, by taking $n$ as the closest integer to $e^{(2k+1)\pi}$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$ (for example, integers between $e^{(2k+1)\pi}$ and $e^{(2k+1.5)\pi}$), we have that $\{W_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ frequently belongs to a neighbourhood of $-1$ separated from $1$, hence the limit does not exist.

Comment: The first part of the proof isn't really needed if you expand on the second one. If we show that $W_n$ belong infinitely many times to two separated neighbourhoods, one of $1$ and one of $-1$, then the claim easily follows.

Comment: @Jakobian: the first part is needed to prove that the only possible limit, if existing, is one.

Comment: Yes, consider this as an alternative approach.