# Square summable consescutive differences and boundedness imply convergence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $\{x_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is bounded (say, in a ball at the origin of radius $b$) and which satisfies,

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\|x_{k+1}-x_k\|^2<\infty$$

Must $x_k$ converge? I don't think so but I cannot provide a counter example. I know that, if you remove the assumption of boundedness, then it's not true as the sequence can have summable consecutive differences but be unbounded.

Comment: This is equivalent to say that every coordinate has a sum of squares of differences convergent. We can assume $n = 1$.

Comment: As a counterexample take harmonic series as $x_k$.

Comment: the harmonic series isn't bounded.

Comment: Can you explain why it should be Cauchy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the claim is false.

Take for example $x_k=\cos(\log(k))$ for $k>1$. Then $(x_k)_k$ is bounded, but it is not convergent (see [Analyse of a simple trigonometric sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/949729/analyse-of-a-simple-trigonometric-sequence))

Moreover, by the MVT
$$x_{k+1}-x_k=-\frac{\sin(\log(t_k))}{t_k}$$
with $t_k\in (k,k+1)$
and therefore 
$$|x_{k+1}-x_k|\leq \frac{1}{k}$$
which implies that 
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty|x_{k+1}-x_k|^2<\infty.$$

Comment: Very nice, +1$\,\,$