# Convergence of $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \cos (\log k)$ and $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \sin (\log k)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I was trying to determine if

$$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \cos (\log k)$$

(with $k = 1, 2, \ldots$) converges. $\log$ is the natural logarithm.

I tried the [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Ratio_test),

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{\cos \left[ \log ( k + 1 ) \right]}{\cos \left[ \log ( k ) \right]} = 1$$

but it is not useful to determine the convergence.

According to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20cos%28log%28k%29%29%2C%20k%20from%201%20to%20infty), it diverges. How to prove it?

And what about $\displaystyle \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \sin (\log k)$?

What I can empirically observe is that, regardless of how big $\log k$ can become, its cosine will always be a number $x$ such that $-1 \leq x \leq 1$. But I can't immediately see that this leads to an infinite sum.

---

Trivially, the [term test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test) is:

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \cos (\log k)$$

and this limit is not defined, due to the cosine. Maybe this is sufficient to state that the series diverges.

Comment: Yes, for an infinite series to converge, it is necessary that its terms tend to $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the series converges
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \cos(\log k) = s \in \Bbb R
$$
and let $s_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \cos(\log k)$.

This would imply
$$
\cos(\log(n)) = s_{n} - s_{n-1} \to s-s = 0
$$
by arithmetic of limits, but [$\lim_{n\to\infty} \cos(\log n)$ doesn't exist](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/949847/721316).

The argument that $\sum \sin(\log k)$ diverges should be similar.

Answer (score 2):

$$\log \lfloor e^{2\pi k} \rfloor = \log( e^{2\pi k}+O(1))=
\log e^{2\pi k} +\log(1+ O(e^{-2\pi k}))=2\pi k+O(e^{-2\pi k})$$

Thus $$\lim_{k\to \infty}\cos(\log \lfloor e^{2\pi k} \rfloor )=1$$

Similarly $$\lim_{k\to \infty}\sin(\log \lfloor e^{2\pi (k+1/4)} \rfloor )=1$$

Answer (score 2):

For $k$ sufficiently big, $\log(k+1)-\log k<\frac\pi2$. On the other hand, $\log k$ is unbounded. Therefore, $\log k$ "walks" to $\infty$ in steps so small that it will hit every interval $[2m\pi-\frac\pi4,2m\pi+\frac\pi4]$ with $m\gg0$. That is, we will have $\cos \log k\ge \frac{\sqrt 2}2$ infinitely often.

Comment: Thank you for these very useful observations. If it's possible, can you please provide a link about the assumption $\log (k + 1) - \log k < \pi / 2$? I didn't know this proof.

Comment: @BowPark $\log(k+1)-\log(k) = \log(\frac{k+1}{k}) \to \log(1) = 0$ (by continuity of $\log$) so this eventually gets small enough

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $a_n =\cos (\log n )\to 0$ then of course $a_{10^k} =\cos k \to 0.$ But it is well known  that the last is not true.

Comment: Did you mean $a_{\lfloor e^{2\pi k} \rfloor}$ ?

Comment: log is rather $log_{10}$

Comment: Sorry, can you rephrase your answer? I can not understand it. In my question $\log$ is referred to the natural logarithm.